# Usage of edge-split SSA

Tags: compiler-construction, ssa

The static single assignment (SSA) representation of code is almost but not quite canonical; there are two flavors, vanilla and *edge-split* in which extra nodes are inserted as necessary to cause every loop to have only one back edge. Rationale: adding the edge-split constraint makes certain optimizations slightly easier.

What I really want to know is whether the edge-split constraint is overall worth having, but that's a judgment call, so for a concrete factual question:

Do the following well-known compilers, which use SSA, use the edge-split constraint?

- GCC
- Go
- LLVM
- SpiderMonkey
- V8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From investigation thus far:

This suggests LLVM uses edge-split: http://llvm.org/doxygen/LoopSimplify_8cpp.html#a209bb6a782608a71aa8ec5075970caa3

Go likewise:
https://golang.org/src/cmd/compile/internal/ssa/critical.go